# How to set the default dialer?

Tags: phone-app, default-applications

Where are the configurations to set the default dialer? I installed a new one and want to know where I set the default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to your Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications.

Select the 'All' tab and scroll to the current dialer app.

Scroll down and press the 'Clear defaults' button. Now when you select dial, you should be prompted to select a particular app and also have the opportunity to set a new default.

Comment: It should have automatically done the prompt for you to choose once you downloaded it but this solution guarantees that it will ask you to choose the default.

Comment: @Vian - Unless the way Renato is launching the dialer is actually via a shortcut to a specific dialer. Some launcher apps allow you to place shortcuts on the dock (I vaguely remember Zeam working like this when I tried it).