# Setting Skype as The Default Dialer on Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, phone-app

These two posts, [Setting Default Dialer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16823/how-to-set-the-default-dialer) and [Setting Nexus Custom Dialer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57965/how-to-set-custom-dialer-as-default-on-nexus-5), make it seem straight forward, but it is not.

I am not prompted to choose which dialer to use, it only uses Google Dialer

Neither the Phone nor the Google Dialer apps have defaults set, thus the `clear defaults` button is not enabled.

I consider myself tech savvy and have already spent half an hour trying to figure this out. Unacceptable for something that should be easy.

Comment: When is it that you expect to be prompted for setting the default and it's not happening? After clearing the defaults you could also try restarting the phone and then starting one of them.

Comment: When I touch a phone number in the stock KitKat Contacts app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, after spending considerable time in Nexus and Skype chat support is that Skype does not provide dialer support for Nexus 5 KitKat. Unsure if other manufacturers using  KitKat have the same issue or have delivered a solution.

I was told by Nexus support I could contact LG for a possible solution, but that the change could void my warranty.

The worst part is that this is not obvious from a Google search. Nothing at all on either sites. Support acts like they don't know. Nexus support would not answer the simple straight forward question, can Skype be a dialer.

I find it hard to believe that both companies are not fully aware that this is the situation. The customer suffers. What exactly does poor android support gain Skype? They just had to refund my prepaid year and lost an opportunity for a lifetime revenue stream....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make Skype calls from your phones built in dialer, give this app a try [Skype Default Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nimeshm.skypedefaultdialer).

How about using a custom dialer jut for making phone calls with Skype? Try out the [Sky Dialer for Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nimeshm.skydialer) Android application. It will let you easily call your android contact's phone numbers using Skype.

*Full Disclosure: I am the developer of this app. If you have any suggestions for making the app better, please let me know.*

Answer (score -1):

1. Disable phone defaults. Go to "manage app" in settings, select phone and clear defaults.
2. Go to the menu,remove the phone icon and replace with the Skype dialer

Comment: "Neither of the Phone or Google Dialer apps have defaults set, thus clear defaults button is not enabled." Straight from the OP. What menu allows you to remove phone icon and replace with skype dialer. What does that even mean?